# How to find ViewController for UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a reference to the `ViewController` from a `UITableViewCell` to show `UIAlertController` from external class.

How can I find that reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
```

Comment: This will fail if the root view controller is already presenting some other view controller. The root view controller is not necessarily the table view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy this will work even if the tableVC is pushed over the rootVc , and it's not logically to think that the rootVC is presenting something at the same time of having an active tableVC that needs to run that code snippet  , moreover if the tableVC is presenting something modally this code will run as it's a present from another VC

Comment: It's possible the table view controller was presented from the root controller. Then your answer would cause a crash. And I said nothing about the table view controller already presenting another controller. Your answer makes a lot of assumptions. Yes, it will work under some conditions but it will crash under many others.

Comment: it won't crash it will say that rootVc is currently presenting another VC and discards the present , also you make assumptions that has no relation to the current case , next time provide your magical & perfect  answer !!!

Comment: Unfortunately I try to use the code directly in the second class. And the alert is not visible. I will try other answers too.

Answer (score 3):

You can get an instance of `UIViewController` from `UITableViewCell` using responder chain.

**Responder chain :** 
The responder chain is a series of linked responder objects. It starts with the first responder and end with the app object. If the first responder cannot handle an event, it forwards the event to the next responder in the responder chain. A responder object is an object that can respond to and handle events.

I think below UITableViewCell extension may help you.

**Objective-C Version:**

UITableViewCell+ParentViewController.h

```
@interface UITableViewCell (ParentViewController)
-(UIViewController *)parentViewController;
@end
```

UITableViewCell+ParentViewController.m

```
@implementation UITableViewCell (ParentViewController)

-(UIViewController *)parentViewController{
    UIResponder *parentResponder = nil;
    while (parentResponder != nil) {
        parentResponder = parentResponder.nextResponder;
        if ([parentResponder isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            UIViewController *parentViewController = (UIViewController *)parentResponder;
            return parentViewController;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

you can call below code inside in your UITableViewCell object.

```
 #import "UIView+ParentViewController.h"

 ViewController *parentViewController = cell.parentViewController;
 if (parentViewController){
     [parentViewController:objAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

**Swift Version:**

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

you can call below code inside in your UITableViewCell object.

```
 if let parentViewController = cell.parentViewController as? ViewController {
    self.present(objAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answer in the appropriate language.

Comment: Thanks, for correcting me, I will update it for Objective-C for also.

Answer (score 2):

Walk up the responder chain until you come to the view controller. Once you have the responder that is the view controller, cast it down to a view controller class and go from there.

```
UIResponder* r = myTableViewCell;
while (![r isKindOfClass: [UIViewController class]])
    r = [r nextResponder];
[(UIViewController*)r presentViewController:myAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: 10x again, @matt.