# Dissmiss UITableViewController from button in TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that has a header view class with a UIButton in it that I've linked up in interface builder. I've got it working fine so that when you tap the button the code fires.

However, I have no idea what to write to dismiss the table view when you tap this button.

```
class headerCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBAction func exit () {
        print("got pressed")
        // tried: MyTableView().dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // But did not work, did nothing?
    }
}

class MyTableView: UITableViewController {

// All the code for the tableView is here...

}
```

Comment: Hint: Use the closure.

Comment: Thanks, could I get a bit more than a hint?

Comment: What's stopping you from searching for closure UITableViewCell?

Comment: I'd really just appreciate an answer to my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After experimenting with the various answers, I've found that creating an IBAction is not the best way to do this, and instead I've simply added an IBOutlet for the button, then done this in the TableViewController:

```
@objc func exit () {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell") as! headerCell
        cell.exitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(exit), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyTableView().dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This makes a brand new table view controller and dismisses it. Since it was never even presented, this does nothing

You need to dismiss the one that contains the cell.

This is one way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50334803/3937

But I recommend adding a weak reference to the header cell to the MyTableView and setting it on construction

Also, MyTableView is a ViewController, not a view. So, MyTableViewController is a better name.

Comment: Ok, so how do I access the table view from the IBAction in the tableViewCell class?

Comment: You want to access the table view controller, not the table view. I updated my answer

Comment: Creating an extension just to determine the TableViewController seems like a lot of code to just dismiss a view. I was purposely putting this in an inaction to avoid having to create an IBOutlet instead and assign the target to dismiss on the table view. There must be a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I suggested the simpler way. Add a `weak var MyTableView?` to the header cell that you set after constructing it. Then use that to dismiss

Comment: Where am I constructing it? I don't know what that means. Perhaps some sample code as a solution would be beneficial.

Comment: I’d need to see more of your code. Don’t you construct headerCell in the VC somewhere?

Comment: It's as I've pasted it.  All that is missing is the extended code for the TableViewController which has your standard; numberOfRows in section, viewForHeaderInSection (which is just returning the dequeueReusableCell as! headerCell) etc...